# Any way to disable emojis/smileys/everything?

Tags: emoticons

So, is there any way to COMPLETELY stop showing emojis/smileys in every single app? I'd rather see a blank square than an annoying face.

Why I want to do that? I don't know, I hate them.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to remove in every single app, since some are baked into the app itself. You can remove emojis from your keyboard however as well as from the app in which you are using. As an example, if you have google keyboard, go into settings---> preferences switch emoji switch key off. In apps such as WhatsApp or Macebook messenger, it is not possible without tampering with the app itself.